# Unknown depth list in Go

Tags: arrays, list, dictionary, multidimensional-array, go

I'm trying to get list of categories from database with unknown levels of depth. Is it possible using `map[int][]interface{}` and is it possible at all?

```
type Category struct {
    ID        int
    Name      string
    ParentID  int
}

func GetCategories(db *gorm.DB) map[int][]interface{} {
    var result = make(map[int][]interface{})
    var categories = []Category{}
    db.Where("parent_id = ?", 0).Find(&categories)
    for len(categories) > 0 {
        var ids []int
        for _, cat := range categories {
            ids = append(ids, cat.ID)
            if cat.ParentID == 0 {
                result[cat.ID] = append(result[cat.ID], cat)
            } else {

                // This work only for 2nd level ...
                result[cat.ParentID] = append(result[cat.ParentID], cat)
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Best output would be in JSON array. For example:

```
[
    {id: 1, name: "Car", Parent: 0, Children: []},
    {id: 2, name: "Boat", Parent: 0, Children: [
        {id: 4, name: "Fast", Parent: 2, Children: []},
        {id: 5, name: "Slow", Parent: 2, Children: [
            {id: 6, name: "ExtraSlow", Parent: 5, Children: []},
        ]},
    ]},
    {id: 3, name: "Rocket", Parent: 0, Children: []}
]
```

Comment: It's possible, but should probably be avoided. The type you're looking for is `map[int]interface{}`.

Comment: Can you update the question with an example output for 2/3 levels ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution! I added slice of categories inside Category struct, and request each layer of depth from database stored in `[depth][]Categories{}`. Finally sorting all data from bottom to top.

```
type Category struct {
    ID        int
    Name      string
    ParentID  int
    Children  []Category
}

func GetCategories(db *gorm.DB) []Category {

    // Request data from database
    var categories = []Category{}
    var store = [][]Category{}
    db.Where("parent_id = ?", 0).Find(&categories)
    for len(categories) > 0 {
        var ids []int
        for _, cat := range categories {
            ids = append(ids, cat.ID)
        }
        store = append(store, categories)
        categories = []Category{}
        db.Where("parent_id in (?)", ids).Find(&categories)
    }

    // Sort and move children to parent
    lastLayer := len(store) - 1
    for lastLayer >= 0 {
        if (lastLayer - 1 >= 0) {
            for _, child := range store[lastLayer] {
                for i, parent := range store[lastLayer -1] {
                    if parent.ID == child.ParentID {
                        store[lastLayer -1][i].Children = append(store[lastLayer -1][i].
                            Children, child)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        lastLayer--;
    }

    return store[0]
}

// Return content as JSON response in WebApp
func Output(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(GetCategories(databaseConnection))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just store every member in the base level in the map and then have a list of all of it's children.

You can then use the map in the same way you would use the array `ids`.

```
func GetCategories(db *gorm.DB) map[int][]interface{} {
    var result = make(map[int][]interface{})
    var categories = []Category{}
    db.Where("parent_id = ?", 0).Find(&categories)
    if len(categories) > 0 {
        for _, cat := range categories {
            if _, ok := result[cat.ID]; !ok {
                result[cat.ID] = make([]interface{}, 0, 5)
            }

            if cat.ParentID != 0 {
                if _, ok := result[cat.ParentID]; !ok {
                    result[cat.ParentID] = make([] interface{}, 0, 5)
                }
                result[cat.ParentID] = append(result[cat.ParentID], cat)                
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

It's not exactly clear what you want to do but this will put all of the parents in the entry "0" of the map eliminating the need for a recursive data structure to store all of your categories.

Comment: There are error when compiling this code in line result[cat.ParentID] = append(result[cat.ParentID], cat)

Comment: Error: `first argument to append must be slice; have interface {}`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I have edited the answer. You should change `result[cat.ID] = make([]Category, 0, 5)` to `result[cat.ID] = make([]interface{}, 0, 5)` and then do type assertion on the way out.